# Is there a programmatic way to configure VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I m writing a brew script to set up my environment at my new workplace. I have kind of figured out how to download VSCode. I would additionally like to be able to configure VScode and install language support and set keybindings. I googled around and got documents and blogs for doing this via UI...Can I do this on CLI ?

Comment: create an extension pack, an extension containing a dependency list on other extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install language support / extensions with the main binary:

```
code --install-extension ms-python.python
```

More at [Command line extension management](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_command-line-extension-management).